# github actions docker metadata cannot understand how the tags are assigned

Tags: docker, github-actions

I'm trying to wrap my head around https://github.com/docker/metadata-action and how the tags are assigned.  Can someone please explain what this table means and how the tags are assigned.

[image]

Also what does the following do

[image]

When I look at the output that is produced as part of this action I see a lot

[image]

However for the actual docker image that gets pushed, it only gets the `sha` value.  I'm not sure how this works.