# Cannot get correct tag using docker/metadata-action

Tags: docker, github-actions

I have a github workflow to build a docker image. The workflow runs after another one that runs semantic release on the repository, so that the code version is updated and a new tag is created.

What I want to achieve is to build the docker image and push it to the registry both with the `main` tag and with the updated version tag (i.e., an image tag equal to the git tag).
I'm using the `docker/metadata-action` for this. I've read the [documentation](https://github.com/docker/metadata-action#typeref) and other relevant ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69848816/github-actions-docker-metadata-cannot-understand-how-the-tags-are-assigned), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66017161/add-a-tag-to-a-docker-image-if-theres-a-git-tag-using-github-action?rq=1)), but I can't understand how the `tags` parameter works.

What I tried is the following:

```
name: Build
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Semantic Release"]
    types:
      - completed

env:
  REGISTRY: <azure-registry>
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:

  build-app:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
          # Catching tag is not working
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=semver,pattern={{raw}}
            type=ref,event=tag

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          file: docker/Dockerfile
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

The job is correctly running after the commit done by the semantic release action, so that I think that all needed information (branch main and latest version tag) are available for the build job, but the metadata-action doesn't catch the tag at all. The output of the relevant step is the following:

[image]

and the only tag that is created for the docker image is `main`.

Maybe it's a simple issue, but what am I missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Im still having this issue as well?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up using the *main* tag to enable ci/cd on Azure Web Apps, even if it was not the most valuable option in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, appreciate it. I did some more testing.... Using a merge commit, I was able to get latest populated. To release a version, I use the second one, this is only going to happen if I tag the release. The first one will always ensure latest is up to date. 

type=raw,value=latest,enable=true
type=semver,pattern={{version}}